# Issue getting split tar.gz file to recombine and extract. Not a valid .gz archive

Tags: linux, tar, gzip

I have a tar.gz archive that has been split apart like so -

```
files.tar.gz.part-aa.gz
...
...
...
files.tar.gz.part-ap.gz
```

I combine them using the cat command -

`cat files* > files.tar.gz` This combines the files into a 16 GB tar.gz file (which is expected)

If I try to run `tar -zxf files.tar.gz` I get the following error -

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

If I check the status of the file, I get this output -

`file files.tar.gz` then the output I get is weird - it says - 
`files.tar.gz: data`

Any ideas?

EDIT -

I ran some of the commands that you guys were mentioning I should try.  Here are the results -

Ran the following commands on several different file parts. As you will see, the output is different for some file parts.

```
Command Run: gunzip files.tar.gz.part-ap.gz
Output/Response: gzip: filestar.gz.part-ap.gz: not in gzip format

Command Run: file files.tar.gz.part-ap.gz
Output/Response: files.tar.gz.part-ap.gz: data

Command Run: gzip -d files.tar.gz.part-ap.gz
Output/Response: gzip: files.tar.gz.part-ap.gz: not in gzip format

Command Run: file files.tar.gz.part-ah.gz
Output/Response: files.tar.gz.part-ah.gz: 8086 relocatable (Microsoft)

Command Run: file files.tar.gz.part-ak.gz
Output/Response: files.tar.gz.part-ak.gz: data
```

Thanks.

Comment: The glob could theoratically match the output too and that could cause problems. Have you tried `cat files.tar.gz.part-* > files.tar.gz` ?

Comment: What does `file files.tar.gz.part-aa.gz` say?

Comment: Did you create a tar file, compress it, split it, then compress the split files? That's my guess, based on `files.tar.gz.part-aa.gz` maybe gzip cowardly refused to compress the already compressed split files?

Comment: Question has been updated with the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intepreting the file extensions, it looks like these are compressed portions of a compressed archive; try this:

```
 gunzip files.tar.gz.part-??.gz
 cat files.tar.gz.part-?? > files.tar.gz
 tar xf files.tar.gz
```

Comment: When I try to gunzip any of the files, I get the following error -

`gunzip files.*`
`gzip: files.tar.gz.part-aa.gz: not in gzip format`
`gzip: files.tar.gz.part-ab.gz: not in gzip format`


etc.

Comment: I updated the question with the outputs of what you suggested.